# Error getting container id in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline script where I'm trying to link several containers together (a liberty container, oracle container and a maven jdk container).

First I create the oracle container:

```
db = docker.build('oracle', 'docker/oracle').run("-p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521")
```

Then link it to my liberty container which seems to work ok:

```
wlp = docker.build('liberty', 'docker/liberty').run("-p 9080:9080 --link=${db.id}:oracle")
```

But when I try to link it to the maven one:

```
mvn.inside('-v $M2_REPO:/m2repo --link=${db.id}:oracle ') {
```

I get the following error in jenkins:

> Failure: java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8'.
>   Error: docker: Error response from daemon: Could not get container for
>   ${db.id}. See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.

Could this be related to the fact that it's using the `inside` call rather than `run` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `${db.id}` is not replaced (or groovy speak: [interpolated](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)) inside the *Pipeline DSL script* because you put are using *single* quotes.

Adjust your command to **use double quotes** instead:

```
mvn.inside("-v \$M2_REPO:/m2repo --link=${db.id}:oracle") {
```

I suppose you don't want to have `$M2_REPO` interpolated, thus it is *escaped* by prepending a `\`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what language it is but docker build looks for a file "Dockerfile" in current directory. So
`docker.build('oracle', 'docker/oracle')`
has some problem because its already build image with `tag docker/oracle`
you just have to run this image not to build.